# User input with timeout

Tags: 14.04, bash, default, input

I am using a script to manage stuff on external dives. At the end I want to give the user the option to leave or dismount the drives. I'd like to add a timeout and use the second option (do nothing) if the user has not responded.

I am fairly new to Linux and the References I have found so far are way too cryptic for my current level of linux-ness. It seems the Reference writers assume everyone is already fluent in Linux. :)

How do I add a timeout to this or a better way of doing this with a timeout and default action?

note: "myDrives" is my own program to handle the closing of files etc and dismount

```
echo "Do you want to un-Mount the External Drives?"
echo ""
select yn in "yes" "no"; do
  case $yn in
    yes ) sudo myDrives --unmount; 
          break;;
    no ) break;;
  esac
done
kill -9 $PPID
```

Comment: You can simply use a new line rather then a second echo \n , you also need input validation, what happens if the user inputs y , n , or something else like "kjhdfklahs" ? See also http://www.bashguru.com/2009/09/how-to-read-user-input-within-time.html

Comment: You can also use printf rather then echo and see http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536112/how-to-insert-a-new-line-in-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using the `-t timeout` option of the bash `read` builtin:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  read -t10 -p "Do you want to un-Mount the External Drives? (Y/N): "
  if [ $? -gt 128 ]; then
    echo "timed out waiting for user response"
    break
  fi

  case $REPLY in
  [yY]*)
    echo "do it"
    break
    ;;
  [nN]*)
    echo "don't do it"
    break
    ;;
  *) echo "Please enter Y or N"
     ;;
  esac
done
```

See `help read` from the bash prompt, or `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks, this is more simple for me to understand at my current level of Linux. But then I like simple anyway, always easier to read and understand some months later.

Comment: It works in my terminal but not in a function I see `read: Illegal option -t` on GNU bash, version 5.0.17. I guess I'm in batch mode.

Comment: @Tomachi how exactly are you running the script? `Illegal option -t` is the error that you'd get if the `read` command is executed with `sh` instead of `bash`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s\n" "Do you want to un-Mount the External Drives?" 
timeout --foreground 10 bash -c '
    select sel in "yes" "no"
    do
        echo "$REPLY"
        break
    done' | while read -r answer; do
        echo ">>Got from user: $answer"
        case "$answer" in
            "yes") echo "Unmounting stuff" ;;
        esac
done
```

Key points to note:

- `timeout` requires an actual process, not shell command. Here we spawn `bash` shell as separate process and let it do the job of driving `select`.
- `printf` is used outside of `timeout` to avoid sending its text via pipe
- `while read -r answer; do . . .done` will operate if and only if it received something via pipe. Thus if the previous `bash` process timed-out , it won't run - there's your default action of not doing anything.
- if the `while` loop received something via pipe, it will check whether it's the `yes` answer, otherwise - it will do nothing

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer the  option SteelDriver gave. I do appreciate you taking the time to also describe what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TMOUT](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-TMOUT) variable which is considered by `select`:

```
echo "Do you want to un-Mount the External Drives?"
TMOUT=10 # 10 seconds time-out
select yn in "yes" "no"; do
  case $yn in
    "yes" ) echo "unmount" ;;
    "no" ) echo "don't unmount" ;;
  esac
  break;
done
if [ -z "$yn" ] ; then
  echo "default action"
fi
```